# Windows: Recursively convert FLAC to MP3 w/ ffmpeg

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, conversion, mp3, flac

I have ffmpeg installed and use batch files to convert MP4 h.264 to MKV x.265 successfully, but I have a problem with converting FLAC files to 320 kbps MP3 w/ no metadata needed. Although [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26109837/convert-flac-to-mp3-with-ffmpeg-keeping-all-metadata) posts [explain](https://superuser.com/questions/516739/cant-convert-flac-to-mp3-with-ffmpeg) how to do this in Linux, their scripts don't solve this problem when run in the command prompt of Windows.

The command line script I have created to convert to MP3 has this line:

```
for %%A in (*.flac) do ffmpeg -i "%%~nA.flac" -c:v copy -b:a 320k "%%~nA.mp3"
```

Not being adept at Powershell, I am looking for a command line solution. I don't care if metadata survives or not.

How may I modify that to convert all FLAC files in the current directory and all sub directories beneath it (as shown in the first link above for Linux)?

Comment: You don't really need help with the ffmpeg part. Just add `-c:v copy` to your command in case the FLAC inputs have album images. So I recommend changing the title because you need help with the recursive part using batch, cmd, powershell or whatever. Otherwise the title alone looks like you need help using ffmpeg when that's not the real problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following `.bat` file should do it:

```
for /R %%A in (*.flac) do ffmpeg -i "%%A" -c:v copy -b:a 320k "%%~dpnA.mp3"
```

You may test it first with this script:

```
for /R %%A in (*.flac) do echo ffmpeg -i "%%A" -c:v copy -b:a 320k "%%~dpnA.mp3"
```

Explanation for the above substitutions
(they are combined in the script above):

- `%~dA`        - expands %A to a drive letter only
- `%~pA`        - expands %A to a path only
- `%~nA`        - expands %A to a file name only

Answer (score 3):

```bat
@echo off 

cd /d "%~dp0" & setlocal 
set "_flag1=-c:v copy -b:a 320k"
set "_flag2=-hide_banner -v error -stats"
set "_ffmpeg="C:\Program Files\FFmpeg\Bin\FFmpeg.exe" -i"

for /r %%i in (*.Flac)do %_ffmpeg% "%%~i" %_flag1% "%%~dpni.mp3" %_flag2%
%__AppDir__%timeout.exe /t 5 /nobreak |echo=Is Done! & endlocal & goto :eof
```

---

- The same without defining/using variables:

```bat
@echo off & setlocal & cd /d "%~dp0"

for /r %%i in (*.Flac)do "C:\Program Files\FFmpeg\Bin\FFmpeg.exe" -i ^
  "%%~i" -c:v copy -b:a 320k "%%~dpni.mp3" -hide_banner -v error -stats
  
%__AppDir__%timeout.exe /t 5 /nobreak |echo=Is Done! & endlocal & goto :eof
```

---

Do you really need to use ***.Flac*** twice?
And you gonna always save all converted files in the same folder (work directory)?

> `for %%A in (.flac) do ffmpeg -i "%%~nA.flac" -c:v copy -b:a 320k "%%~nA.mp3"`
> `for /R %% A in (.flac)` from `ffmpeg -i "%%~pI%%~nA.flac" -b:a 320k "%%~nA.mp3"` fails with the same error as noted before...

**1.** Remove `n` and `.flac`

```bat
for %%A in (*.flac) do ffmpeg -i "%%~nA.flac" -c:v copy -b:a 320k "%%~nA.mp3"
```

- **Obs.: 1** The `For` loop variable `"%%~A"` provide to you the full path to the input file, you don't need to crop name and/or add explicitly:

```bat
"%~Drive\\Path\\Name.Flac"
"%%~dpn.Flac"
"%%~N.Flac"

rem :: use
ffmpeg -i  "%%#~A" ...
```

**2.** Use `For /R`:

```bat
For /R %%i in (*.flac)do ...
```

**3.** Consider define/adding a `drive:\folder\` to save the target encoded file, not just a name, if **not** to save it in the same work directory your bat are in.

```bat
 ... (...)do.... ffmpeg ... "%%~dpni.mp3"
```

- **Obs.: 2** To save your `.mp3` in the current/work directory, youc can use:

```bat
 ... (...)do.... ffmpeg ... "%%~ni.mp3"
 ... (...)do.... ffmpeg ... ".\%%~ni.mp3"
 ... (...)do.... ffmpeg ... "%CD%\%%~ni.mp3"
```

- **Obs.:: 3** All metadata survives!!

---

One suggest using `For /F + where /R`

```bat
@echo off

setlocal & cd /d "%~dp0"    

for /f delims^= %%i in ('
2^>nul %__AppDir__%where.exe /r . *.flac
')do "C:\Program Files\FFmpeg\Bin\FFmpeg.exe" -i "%%~i" -c:v ^
     copy -b:a 320k "%%~dpni.mp3" -hide_banner -v error -stats

%__AppDir__%timeout.exe 5 /nobreak |echo=Is Done! & endlocal & goto :eof
```

- **Obs.:: 4** For break line using `^`, do not use any **spaces/character** after the caret:

[image]

---

**Additional resources:**

- [`Set /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html)
- [`For /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)
- [`For /F`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)
- [`For /R`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_r.html)
- [`Where /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/where.html)
- [`Timeout /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/timeout.html)
- [Redirection](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/redirection.php)

  - `|`, `<`, `>`, `2>`, etc.
- [Conditional Execution](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html)

  - [`||`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html) and [`&&`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html)
- [`Local Environment | Function` | Also Refer: `Goto :EOF`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-functions.html)

  - [`Setlocal`](https://ss64.com/nt/setlocal.html) & [`Endlocal`](https://ss64.com/nt/setlocal.html)
- [Split long commands in multiple lines through Windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69068/split-long-commands-in-multiple-lines-through-windows-batch-file)
- [How does the Windows Command Interpreter [`cmd.exe`] Parse Scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4094699/6819406)